# От чего зависит отправит ли Oracle join в Impala или будет джойнить у себя?

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, impala

**Ситуация:**

Есть запрос с двумя джойнами:

```
SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_A A
  JOIN VIEW_B B
    ON A.FIELD_1 = B.FIELD_1
  JOIN VIEW_C C
    ON C.FIELD_2 = A.FIELD_2
   AND C.FIELD_3 = B.FIELD_3
```

Каждое представление в этом запросе является представлением по типу

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_X AS
  SELECT "filed_1" AS FIELD_1
       , "filed_2" AS FIELD_2
       , "filed_3" AS FIELD_3
  FROM REMOTE_USER.REMOTE_TABLE_X@LINK_TO_REMOTE;
```

Где LINK_TO_REMOTE ведет в импалу (импала именует поля маленькими буквами, поэтому они в кавычках).

**Проблема:**

Оптимизатор решил, что не смотря на то, что все три представления смотрят на удаленные таблицы в импале, имеет смысл не отправлять целиком запрос в импалу (чтобы джойн произошел на её стороне удаленно), а две таблицы улетают с джойном (то есть, придет уже объединенный результат двух таблиц), а вот третья выкачивается целиком и джойн происходит уже на стороне оракла. Учитывая объемы, которые будут футболиться туда-сюда по сети, время запроса увеличивается на два порядка.

**Вопрос:**

Можно ли явно подсказать оптимизатору чтобы он отправил весь запрос в импалу и получил только ответ? Если нет, то что может влиять на это? Например, я заметил, что left join никогда не улетает в импалу, или при наличии функции nvl() в on секции джойна запрос также не спускается в импалу.

Comment: Навык пока в зачаточном состоянии, мне бы хотя бы понять в какую сторону копать эту тему.

Comment: а если попробовать создать VIEW с джоинами в Impala и пользоваться им?

Comment: @MaxU боюсь, это не наш вариант. Это можно было бы применить если бы кейс с необходимостью джойна двух таблиц на стороне импалы был редкий, но и справочников, и сорсов очень не мало, поэтому нужно все-таки понять как этим можно управлять.

Comment: а DB_LINKи у вас для всех трех таблиц/представлений одинаково называются?

Comment: @MaxU да, все линки одни и те же и все представления находятся в одной схеме.

Comment: и вообще мне кажется, что у вас логическая ошибка. Вы пытаетесь объединять несколько __удаленных__ таблиц/представлений __на стороне Oracle__, но почему-то ожидаете, что Oracle Optimizer знает всю необходимую ему информацию об Impala таблицах.

Comment: @MaxU да, в импале почти исключительно сырые данные и управление происходит из оракла (на нем уже аналитика и обработка промежуточных данных). Тянуть все источники в оракл нет никакого смысла, конечно. Мопед, как говорится, не мой. Люди различными шаманствами в большинстве случаев всё-таки добиваются ожидаемого результата уже не один год. Но исключительно методом тыка. Хотелось бы понять основательно как взаимодействуют оракл с импалой.

Comment: мне даже трудно себе представить как общаются между собой Oracle Query Optimizer и Impala Query Optimizer. Возможно каждый из них считает себя главным и рассматривает все удаленные источники как простое и глупое хранилище данных

Comment: А вы на стороне Oracle всё в представленние (inline и обычное) обернуть пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

может помочь хинт [+DRIVING_SITE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABEGIJC), но придётся немного изменить запрос, добавив в него хоть одну таблицу с удалённой базы явно, а не через view. этой таблицей может быть и dual, например:

```
SELECT /*+ DRIVING_SITE(D) */ *
  FROM VIEW_A A
  JOIN VIEW_B B
    ON A.FIELD_1 = B.FIELD_1
  JOIN VIEW_C C
    ON C.FIELD_2 = A.FIELD_2
   AND C.FIELD_3 = B.FIELD_3
  JOIN DUAL@LINK_TO_REMOTE D ON 1=1
```